# Facebook Access Token Expires

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-access-token

I am writing login system.I am reading this document

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/using-auto-login/

But this example uses access token for identify user.But access tokens expires in max 60 days.How can I identify user when expires the access token ?

Answer (score 0):

Just before the token is going to expire, the user have to go to the login/auth step again and you'll get the normal token. Then replace this with the extended one. This is the only way.

You cant just have  a token of a user and use it forever; the user have to visit your app again!